# Android Developer Console won't load because a SSL error

Tags: android, google-chrome, ssl

I have a weird problem and I can't find any solution. I have my first app ready to be publish, so I paid my developer fee to Google. It's supposed that now I can access to the Android Developer Console web and... nope. I can't access to this url https://market.android.com/publish/receipt or this one  https://play.google.com/apps/publish/v2/ or this one https://play.google.com/apps/publish/. All of them returns the same error [image] (Using Google Chrome v.29.0.1547.57 from Ubuntu 64bits, neither Firefox (last version) from Linux or Windows or Chrome from Windows).

I have looked all over the web, I have configured the option "use ssl 2.0" on Chrome and now I have no clue what's happening.

BTW, I'm not behind any proxy and I'm logged with the same account I used to pay the fee.

Can anyone of you b ring some light here please? THanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem - it turns out Google didn't like the DNS settings I had on my mac. Make sure you don't use custom DNS or proxy servers and try again.

Comment: This was also my problem. I'm using Unblock.us, configured in my router. Thanks much!